# How to calculate the total sum except one row in a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I want to calculate the total sum of all parameter in a `dataframe` except one named `Production-avg` in the below python code:

code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Example DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['Production', 'Production', 'Production', 'Production', 'Production'], 'parameter': ['hello', 'Production-avg', 'Production-etf', 'ktf', 'kfc'], 'actuals': [10, 30, 50, 70, 90], 'bp': [15, 35, 55, 75, 95]})
df.loc['total'] = df.select_dtypes(include=['int64']).sum()
print(df)
```

current output:

```
         category       parameter  actuals     bp
0      Production           hello     10.0   15.0
1      Production  Production-avg     30.0   35.0
2      Production  Production-etf     50.0   55.0
3      Production             ktf     70.0   75.0
4      Production             kfc     90.0   95.0
total         NaN             NaN    250.0  275.0
```

Expected output:

```
           category       parameter  actuals     bp
 0      Production           hello     10.0   15.0
 1      Production  Production-avg     30.0   35.0
 2      Production  Production-etf     50.0   55.0
 3      Production             ktf     70.0   75.0
 4      Production             kfc     90.0   95.0
 total         NaN             NaN    220.0  240.0
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to get the expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use boolean indexing to filter out rows where `parameter` column value is `Production-avg`

```py
df.loc['total'] = (df.select_dtypes('number').drop('total')
                   [df['parameter'] != 'Production-avg'].sum())
# or
df.loc['total'] = (df.query('parameter != "Production-avg"')
                   .select_dtypes('number').drop('total').sum())
```

As mozway suggests, some modification in your original code:

1. Use `.select_dtypes('number')` to select numeric columns to include `int` and `float` type.
2. Use `.drop('total')` to drop the existing `total` row to avoid summing that row to new result.

```
print(df)

         category       parameter  actuals     bp
0      Production           hello     10.0   15.0
1      Production  Production-avg     30.0   35.0
2      Production  Production-etf     50.0   55.0
3      Production             ktf     70.0   75.0
4      Production             kfc     90.0   95.0
total         NaN             NaN    220.0  240.0
```

Comment: You might want to add `drop('total')` to avoid adding the total if already existing: `.select_dtypes('number').drop('total')` is probably the best

Comment: @mozway Thank you mozway, good point for excluding `total` row from summation and using `number` instead of `int64` for selecting possible float type columns.

Comment: How to calculate the total sum of all parameter in a dataframe except one named `'Production-avg` if it is in the dataframe.otherwise ,simply calculate the total sum@
Ynjxsjmh

Comment: @AbinBenny What do you mean, I think this question is same with your original.